Callback function not executing in Django Celery group when one task fails
I am working on a Django project that uses Celery to execute a group of tasks asynchronously. I noticed that when one of the tasks in the group fails, the callback function is not executed.
Here is an overview of my setup:
Task group definition: I use group from celery to run multiple tasks together.
Callback function: A function should execute after all tasks in the group are completed, regardless of their success or failure.
Problem: If any task in the group fails, the callback function is not triggered.


@shared_task
def fun1():
 
    return "Task 1 completed successfully"


@shared_task
def fun22():
    print('Task22')

    raise ValueError('Error')


@shared_task
def fun3():
    return "Task 3 completed successfully"


@shared_task(bind=True)
def callback_task(results):
    print("Callback@@@@@@@@@@@@@@")
    processed_results = []
    errors = []

    for result in results:
        if isinstance(result, dict) and result.get("status") == "error":
            errors.append(result)
        else:
            processed_results.append(result)

    if errors:
        print(f"Errors encountered: {errors}")
    else:
        print(f"All tasks succeeded. Results: {processed_results}")

    return {"processed_results": processed_results, "errors": errors}


@shared_task
def error_handler():
    print('Handler')
    return "error handler"


@shared_task
def fun2():
    task_group = [
        fun1.s(),
        fun22.s().on_error(error_handler.s()),
        fun3.s(),
    ]

    result = chord(task_group, callback_task.s()).apply_async()

    print(f"Group Id: {result.id}")
    return result.id

Expected Behavior:
Even if one task fails, the callback function should execute and handle the results or failures.
Actual Behavior:
When one task in the group fails (e.g., task2), the callback function is not executed.
